# Reusing a pointer to array after deletion

Tags: c++

This the code:

```
char * asd = new char[10];
delete [] asd;

asd = new char[20];
```

Questions:

1. Doesn't the delete operation on pointers deletes the allocated memory being pointed to by the pointer?
2. is alright to reuse pointers after performing delete it on?

Comment: Why don't you read up on what `delete` does?

Comment: Note that you aren't "reusing an array" either. `asd` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Instead of raw arrays and pointers, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Doesn't the delete operation on pointers deletes the allocated memory
>   being pointed to by the pointer?

Yes.

> is alright to reuse pointers after performing delete it on?

Yes, that's fine, as long as you set the pointer to the address of a different, valid object, which is what you are doing with your second invocation of `new[]`.

Note that your question title "Reusing an array after deletion", is irrelevant to your question. You are not reusing an array that has been deleted, you are just reusing a pointer that used to point to an array which is now deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer.